# store my fetched data to my array const = players

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

newbie here. My target is to store my fetched data in my array. T

This is my script. This script function is to join 2 data in 1 if they have the same level. For example player 1 has level 1, player 6 has level 1 also, which means that Player 1 and player 6 will be joined in 1 array. This current script is static, it is not dynamic yet. My target is to store my fetched data here rather than the static ones. Thank you in advance, any help will be appreciated.

```
const players = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'player1',
        level: '1',
    
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'player2',
        level: '2',
     
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'player3',
        level: '3',
  
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'player4',
        level: '3',
      
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'player5',
        level: '2',
     
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'player6',
        level: '1',
     
    }
];

const matching = (list, keyGetter) => {
    let mapping = {};
    const map = new Map();
    list.forEach((item) => {
        const key = keyGetter(item);
        const collection = map.get(key);
        if (!collection) {

            map.set(key, [item]);
        } else {

            collection.push(item);
        }
    });

    Array.from(map).map(([key, value]) => Object.assign(mapping, { [key]: value }));
    return mapping
}

const result = matching(players, ({ level}) => { return level});

console.log("RESULT", result);
```

this is the result of the above script

[image: Result of above script]

In this function, this is how i fetch my data. My target is to store my fetched data to the array i made above const = players

**views:**

```
  <table id="table_player" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
            
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Player</th>  
                    <th>Level</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            
            </tbody>
 
            
         </table>
```

**ajax:**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
        //datatables
        table = $('#table_player').DataTable({ 
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'print', 'csv', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdfHtml5'
            ],
           
            "processing": false, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.    
            "order": [], //Initial no order.
            
     
            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/ajax_list')?>",
                 "type": "POST",
                    "data": function (dateParams) {
                    
                     return $.extend( { "start": dateParams.start,
            "end": dateParams.end,}, dateParams, {
           });
        },
             },
     
            //Set column definition initialization properties.
            "columnDefs": [
                { 
                    "targets": [ 0 ], //first column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
                { 
                    "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
     
            ],
     
        });
       });
```

**Controller:**

```
     public function ajax_list()
            {
                
                
                $list = $this->model->get_datatables();
                $data = array();
                $no = $_POST['start'];
                foreach ($list as $person) {
                    $no++;
                    $row = array();
                    $row[] = $person->id;
                    $row[] = $person->player;
                    $row[] = $person->level;
      
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                
                $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->model->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->model->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
                );
                //output to json format
                echo json_encode($output);
            }
```

**Model:**

```
        var $table = 'tbl_player';
        var $column_order = array(null,'id','player','level');
        var $order = array('id' => 'desc');
        var $column_search = array('id','player','level');
        //set column field database for datatable orderable      //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable     var $order = array('id' => 'desc'); // default order
        
        private function _get_datatables_query()
        {
            
            
            
            $this->db->from($this->table);
            
            $i = 0;
            
            foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column
            {
                if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
                {
                    
                    if($i===0) // first loop
                    {
                        $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                        $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    }
                    
                    if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                        $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
                }
                $i++;
            }
            
            if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
            {
                $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
            }
            else if(isset($this->order))
            {
                $order = $this->order;
                $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
            }
        }
        
        function get_datatables()
        {
            $this->_get_datatables_query();
            if($_POST['length'] != -1)
                $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result();
        }
    
        
        
        function count_filtered()
        {
            $this->_get_datatables_query();
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->num_rows();
        }
        
        public function count_all()
        {
            $this->db->from($this->table);
            return $this->db->count_all_results();
        }
```

Comment: Onload of page make ajax call and save that value return from server-end . Or you can use [row().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) to get data from datatable whenever you need .

Comment: Thank you, I'll study about it and apply.